# Display user registration date

Tags: users, date, user-registration

I want to show user registration date like

> Member since: 15,dec 2012.

I have a code

```
<?php echo date("M Y", strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered)); ?>
```

but it show same date in all users profiles. Can some one please tell me how I fix that.

Comment: Please add the complete code how you get the user data.

Comment: For me this worked: https://www.ideiplus.com/show-user-registration-date-in-wordpress-website/ I have wp 4.4 and a mythemeshop theme.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`get_current_user_id()` give you the user id of the **logged in** user. And that is: you.

You have to get all users:

```
<?php
        $users = get_users();

        foreach( $users as $user ) {

            $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

            $registered = $udata->user_registered;

            printf( '%s member since %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name, date( "M Y", strtotime( $registered ) ) );
        }
```

Comment: but they show all user registration date,
i want to show every member profile page with his joining date.
please provide me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4427538

Comment: @Ralf912 Where exactly do we get to place your code? Thanks.

Comment: functions.php or plugin. wherelse? because it is not theme specific, a plugin would be the best place.

Comment: @Ralf912. On a multisite, can we just use the above code as a drop-in plugin (no plugin headers) so it can be independent from all themes and auto-activated for all sites?

Comment: @Ralf912 You are soooo right. !!! I didn't want to break anything. I will just make a new test site and try it out. Thank you and sorry for all the fuss.

Answer (score 2):

```
$udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );
$registered = $udata->user_registered;
printf(
    $table,
    'Registered',
    date( "M Y", strtotime( $registered ) )
);
```

Comment: Little explanation would be great!

Comment: wherever you want to print the date and time put this above code..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for front-end, this is the best example:

```
//Get post author ID
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post->ID );

//Get the registration date
$registered_date = get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $post_author_id );

//Convert to desired format
$output = date( 'F j, Y', strtotime($registered_date));

//Echo
echo $output;
```