# How to change a user's role conditionally to expire after two weeks

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

Currently on my website I have two roles created - Trial and Expired. When a user registers it defaults them to trial. I want to run a function that will automatically change their role to expired after two weeks. This is the code I have currently, but am missing something:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', function($username, $user) {

   $toExpire = [ 'trial'];

   $toRemove = array_intersect($user->roles, $toExpire);

   if (count($user->roles) < 2 || empty($toRemove)) {
     // nothing to do if the user has just 1 role or none of the roles you want to expire
     return;
   }


   $downloadTimestamp = get_last_download_timestamp_for_user($user->ID);

   $dayLimit = 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS; // expire after 30 days

   if ((time() - $dayLimit) < $paymentTimestamp) {
     // do nothing if not enough time passed
     return;
   }

   if (! array_diff($toExpire, $toRemove)) {
     // if an user has ONLY roles that might expire, keep the first role
     array_shift($toRemove);
   }
}
```

We currently have the Ultimate Member plugin installed which doesn't give us this functionality in the plugin. I tried Expire users which doesn't work either :(

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
A

Comment: Setting the day-limit to 30 days out each time the function is called is the problem.. I would compare the current date `date()` in php & compare with the date the user registered: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77876/display-user-registration-date then re-assign the user-role based on that.