# Show posts who published after registration date

Tags: users, permissions

i will make a membership system in WordPress with indeed ultimate membership pro and I would like users not to see posts that were made before the date they registered.

I want: They can still see the posts, but only from the day they registered ... I've been searching, but most likely I don't know exactly.

Thanks

Comment: This can not be accomplished with permissions. You will have to write your own loop and filter posts by date.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` can add extra arguments to queries, you could use that to turn them into date queries, but you would need to get the registration date from somewhere, and you'll need to look into Ultimate Membership Pro support for that. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here and not in this sites scope

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski writing a replacement loop is unnecessary with `pre_get_posts`, a replacement loop could trivially be bypassed with an RSS feed/XMLRPC/REST API or even just adding the right parameters to the URL on a different page

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm looking at `pre_get_posts` - interesting, I see how this might work - thank you! Custom loop will also work if you make all posts hidden by default and reveal only to logged-in users.
And how to find logged-in user registration date can be found in this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77876/display-user-registration-date

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski we do not know that for this plugin, nor should we attempt to research a 3rd party plugin, that's off-topic. Though if you can answer this without using knowledge of Ultimate Membership then do so by posting an answer rather than commenting